# cannot connect to the network

Tags: configuration, network-configuration

```
1/31/2016 13:37:15 PM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on
127.0.0.1:9150  1/31/2016 13:37:15 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server  1/31/2016 14:44:21 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 10; recommendation warn; host 7EA6EAD6FD83083C538F44038BBFA077587DD755 at
194.109.206.212:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 11; recommendation warn; host 9695DFC35FFEB861329B9F1AB04C46397020CE31 at
128.31.0.39:9101)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 12; recommendation warn; host 7BE683E65D48141321C5ED92F075C55364AC7123 at
193.23.244.244:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 13; recommendation warn; host CF6D0AAFB385BE71B8E111FC5CFF4B47923733BC at
154.35.175.225:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 14; recommendation warn; host F2044413DAC2E02E3D6BCF4735A19BCA1DE97281 at
131.188.40.189:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 15; recommendation warn; host 0AD3FA884D18F89EEA2D89C019379E0E7FD94417 at
208.83.223.34:80)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 16; recommendation warn; host 847B1F850344D7876491A54892F904934E4EB85D at
86.59.21.38:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 17; recommendation warn; host BD6A829255CB08E66FBE7D3748363586E46B3810 at
171.25.193.9:80)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 18; recommendation warn; host 74A910646BCEEFBCD2E874FC1DC997430F968145 at
199.254.238.52:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 19; recommendation warn; host 74A910646BCEEFBCD2E874FC1DC997430F968145 at
199.254.238.52:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 20; recommendation warn; host 847B1F850344D7876491A54892F904934E4EB85D at
86.59.21.38:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 21; recommendation warn; host 7EA6EAD6FD83083C538F44038BBFA077587DD755 at
194.109.206.212:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 22; recommendation warn; host 0AD3FA884D18F89EEA2D89C019379E0E7FD94417 at
208.83.223.34:80)  1/31/2016 17:24:11 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5%: Connecting to directory server. (Permission denied [WSAEACCES ]; RESOURCELIMIT; count 23; recommendation warn; host CF6D0AAFB385BE71B8E111FC5CFF4B47923733BC at
154.35.175.225:443)  1/31/2016 17:24:34 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150  1/31/2016 17:24:34 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.  1/31/2016 17:24:34 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150  1/31/2016 17:24:34 PM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: it's a firewall issue. Post your firewall config here, so I'll be able to help you further

Comment: Thanks ..its was antivirus firewall ,I config the policy

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Anytime! Feel free to ask further questions! Can you accept it as an answer to your question?